# MVC Login with repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validates users with login view,controller and repository

### Actions result in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.UserModel user)
{
    CartLibrary.Repository.UserRepository objuserrepository = new CartLibrary.Repository.UserRepository();
     objuserrepository.Login(user.Username, user.Password);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Orders"); 
}
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

### Method in repository

```
public string Login(string Username, string Password )
{
    if (!DB.Users.Any(x => x.Username == Username && x.Password == Password))
    {
        return Username;
    }
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    return Username;
}
```

Comment: Now what's your problem?

Comment: Suggest you look at using [Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). And storing plain text passwords in a database is simply bad practice.

Comment: This is not validating username and password just  redirecting to another page. i want  it to validate username and password and and change the login status

Answer (score 1):

In your Login method you just return string (username).....but you don't set any cookies so......????

So you can after your login method write code:

```
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(objuserrepository.Login(user.Username,user.Password))
{
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(
                 this.TextBox_username.Text.Trim(), flase);

         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket1 = 
            new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                 1,                                   // version
                 this.TextBox_username.Text.Trim(),   // get username  from the form
                 DateTime.Now,                        // issue time is now
                 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),         // expires in 10 minutes
                 false,      // cookie is not persistent
                 "HR"                              // role assignment is stored
                 // in userData
                 );
          HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
            FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket1) );
          Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
}
```